# micro-controller, which language is preferable? high level or assembly

Tags: c#, c, assembly

I want to program a micro controller with 4 I/O ports and 1 serial port and 512 kb of code memory.
I think I should go with assembly. what you guys suggest?
thanks

Comment: It depends entirely on the task at hand. If a good development environment exists (see for example Arduino) there is almost certainly no reason to go down to assembly. Do you need super performance? You don't appear to be short of memory? Why go to assembly?

Comment: usually `c` but depends. C because low level, smaller size etc.. Just an opinion

Comment: Not likely to be done in assembly.  In rare cases you may have to perform tweaks of your C code in assembly, but that is very rare.  512kb sounds like an environment with more than enough resources.  Start in C (I am a systems programmer, have written code for many MC's, have always used C and/or some scripting language the vendor may provide).

Comment: I feel that the typical microcontroller programs _I_ write do not greatly benefit from a higher level language than C, and so I use C due to familiarity, availability of existing code, and fairly good reusability of the higher level functionality between different platforms. Sometimes it may be beneficial to drop down to assembly, and perhaps for some applications (especially with such a large code memory as 512 KB) a higher level language will speed development without unacceptable bloat… Depends on project and personal preference.

Comment: actually this chip meant for the security of vehicles you know, tracking GPS, handling engine and door locks. So great performance isn't an issue is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, using a high-level language, the code is much more readable and maintainable than assembly language, and in my experience most c-compilers produce machine code that is NEARLY as efficient as well-written assembly language...for MOST tasks.  So unless you fear that the (seemingly) copious 512KB of memory MAY not be enough for your needs, I would recommend C.  And generally, coding in assembly (if you are quite efficient at it) will only buy you perhaps a 10% reduction is memory usage.

Comment: thanks, your answer makes it quite clear.actually this micro controller for the security system of vehicles let's assume, dealing with GPS, door locks an all. For security purpose I think we need to go more into machine language than C, what you think about it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "for security purposes"... you can make things more secure, more easily, in C.  Hopefully, you are not actually writing in MACHINE language... the 1's and 0's, but at least assembly language.  But even assembly language is best suited for small tasks and procedures, intended -- perhaps -- to interface in very specific ways with the hardware, such that a high-level language can NOT be used.  Certainly, a complex embedded system, such as you describe, CAN be done all in ASM, but it would be a difficult task, and maintainability would become a major issue.